# How to find an index of clicked tab in QTabWidget in Python QT?

Tags: python, qt

I am developing a simple text editor which has mutlitabs. I want to implement a rightclick menu to rename **clicked (not current)** tab of a QTabWidget instance. To do this I have to find the index of clicked tab. How can I do this?

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MyApplication(...):
    ...

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        tabIndex = ... # <- what should I type here?

        menu = QMenu(self)

        renameAction = menu.addAction("Rename")

        action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))

        if action == renameAction:
            self.renameTabSlot(tabIndex)


    def renameTabSlot(self, tabIndex):
        ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to check to clicked position (i.e. `event.pos ()`) against the tab regions manually. My python is a bit rusty, so here's some C++ code instead. Assuming your tabwidget is called `myTabWidget`:

```
int tabIndex = -1;
{
  QTabBar* tabBar = myTabWidget->tabBar ();

  QPoint globalPos   = this  ->mapToGlobal   (event->pos ());
  QPoint posInTabBar = tabBar->mapFromGlobal (globalPos);

  for (int i=0; i<tabBar->count (); ++i)
  {
    if (tabBar->tabRect (i).contains (posInTabBar))
    {
      tabIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
}

if (tabIndex < 0)
{
  // No tab hit...
  return;
}
```

I didn't compile&run this, but the idea should be clear. Note the `mapToGlobal` and `mapFromGlobal` calls to transform the given event's position into the tab-bars native coordinates. I hope I did it right.

Answer (score 1):

You can add context menus to the QTabBar widgets through code such as:

```
for i,tabbar in enumerate(bars):
    tabbar.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
    renameAction = QtGui.QAction("Rename",tabbar)
    renameAction.triggered.connect(lambda x: self.renameTabSlot(i))
    tabbar.addAction(renameAction)
```

The trick here is that you define a lambda for each tabbar based on its index such that the index will be passed to the rename function.
See [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Handling%20context%20menus) page for more info on handling context menus.